# Confidence intervals on 'cross plots'

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a large set of data comprising triples of points (t, y1, y2). At each t, I have a distribution of y1 and y2 points, each of which is approximately normal.

I would like to create a plot of y1 versus y2 (mean values) and add a 90% or 95% confidence interval envelope.

I would appreciate any advice on how to calculate the confidence intervals in this case such that I can subsequently construct a plot.

Thank you.

**Update and clarification:**

In my field, if y1 is a function of x and y2 is a function of x, a plot of y1 vs y2 over the domain of x is called a 'cross plot'.

Additional information:

- In my application, t is the independent variable and y1 and y2 are dependent variables.
- There is a complex (differential equation based) predictive model that produces many values of y1 and y2 for every value of t.
- There is no explicit model relating y1 and y2.
- I can already create separate confidence interval plots (t vs y1, t
  vs y2).
- For each value of t, I can estimate the mean and standard deviation for y1 and y2.

My aim: For each value of t, say ti, I would like to plot mean(y1i) vs mean(y2i) as a point on my y1 vs y2 plot and then include the confidence interval envelope.

Comment: What is your question here? How to calculate confidence intervals? How to calculate confidence intervals in R? I made a small [reference page](http://rpubs.com/RomanL/7024) for myself on how to (calculate and) plot different intervals using `ggplot2` package. Feel free to browse.

Comment: I suppose the question is... when there is uncertainty in both variables being plotted, what is the appropriate way to construct a  confidence interval plot and are there existing R functions to do this? Thank you for pointing me to your 'reference page', but I cannot access it. Is site registration necessary?

Comment: Based on the information provided, I think this question would be more suited for crossvalidated.com. I have never had any problems accessing RPubs, perhaps it is limited to registered users, I'm not really sure.

Comment: cytochrome No registration is necessary; I just accessed the page without difficulty. What's a 'cross plot'?

Comment: [Seems to be another term for scatterplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-plot). What kind of confidence area do you want to specify, one defined by the bivariate distribution (e.g., Mahalanobis distance), or one defined by a predictive model relating `y1` to `y2`? Sounds like there are repeated measures involved too...How do you want to take this into account? Separate plots for each `t`, ignore `t`, superimpose and color-code points and boundaries for different `t`, etc....? Given the variety of options, please choose 1–3 and [edit](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/109087/edit).